# How to dynamically add & update JSF components from bean?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to generate dynamic chat windows within a PanelGroup. The structure is like this:

```
    <h:panelGroup id="chats">
       <p:dialog id="chatWindow1">

       </p:dialog>
       <p:dialog id="chatWindow2">

       </p:dialog>
    </h:panelGroup>
```

The problem is when I'm adding a new chat window, it's not showing. I think the newly created dialog is not updating [ by RequestContext's update method] since it's not existing yet in view. So, I've to update "chats" panel group in order to see the new dialog. But the problem in that is pre-existing dialogs in that panel group gets updated.

Consider a scenario: user types some text in chat window.Suddenly a new chat window pops up & all his chat text in that pre-existing dialog vanishes.

I just want to prevent that scenario. How can it be done?

Comment: Why exactly did you add `[jsf-1.2]` tag while you don't seem to be using JSF 1.2?

Comment: @BalusC ok.removed the tag.I just wanted to get a working solution & hence bring it under radar of all JSF groups.